# how does [len] became property of arr i.e. (Number(arr[len]) in the following code

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

i am unable to understand that how (Number(arr[len]) is composed. is [len] made the property of **arr**.

```
function arrayMax(arr) {
      var len = arr.length, max = -Infinity;
      while (len--) {
        if (Number(arr[len]) > max) {
          max = Number(arr[len]);
        }
      }
      return max;
    };
```

Comment: When you create an array, the elements are indexed using integers, and the value of `len` is an integer.

Comment: Seems like you should read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably some attempt at a super efficient way of getting the max value in a array.

len variable is badly named in all fairness. It should have been labeled index.

```
function arrayMax(arr) {
  var index = arr.length, max = -Infinity;
  while (index--) {
    if (Number(arr[index]) > max) {
      max = Number(arr[index]);
    }
  }
  return max;
};
```

And arr[index] gets the value at the specified index.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#access_an_array_item_by_its_index

Comment: why we need to remove the array items with " while (index--)" to get the maximum number

Comment: You aren't removing anything. It decrements the integer cloned from arr.length.